# Canvas javascript lineTo method fading

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Im using **lineTo** method from canvas context 2d API to draw some lines but the lines are fading even tho **lineWidth** is being setted.

here is the code

```
const drawData = (canvasContext) => {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#66FF66";
    data.forEach((dataValue, idx) => {
      canvasContext.beginPath();
      canvasContext.lineWidth = 2;
      const data_x_position = (dataValue.x * CHART_WIDTH) / 100 + CHART_X_START;
      const data_y_position = CHART_Y_END - (dataValue.y * CHART_HEIGHT) / 300;
      const nextIdx = data[idx + 1] ? idx + 1 : idx;
      const next_data_x_position =
        (data[nextIdx].x * CHART_WIDTH) / 100 + CHART_X_START;
      const next_data_y_position =
        CHART_Y_END - (data[nextIdx].y * CHART_HEIGHT) / 300;
      canvasContext.moveTo(data_x_position, data_y_position);

      canvasContext.lineTo(next_data_x_position, next_data_y_position);
      canvasContext.arc(
        data_x_position,
        data_y_position,
        2,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI,
        true
      );
      canvasContext.closePath();
      canvasContext.fill();
    });
  };
```

the lines that are "fading" are created using this function

`canvasContext.lineTo(next_data_x_position, next_data_y_position);`

the problem is shown in the following image where the green lines seem to be fading when it gets close to the next point.

I also made a codesandbox with the full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-cray-m2ljw?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: The arc in the path is causing your problem.

Comment: add canvasContext.stroke();
      canvasContext.closePath(); after lineTo and before arc